Is there a way to send UserPrincipalName from Power BI Service to Databricks server for RLS?
I am brand new to databricks and have recently finished putting together my first Semantic Model connecting to our databricks instance using a serverless compute, with an apps own data embedded Power BI setup.
After I set it up I tested how quick it was using filters (mimicking what my RLS would be) and found it to be a quite responsive 2-3 seconds return for each visual.
However, when I setup my RLS which is on my fact table and quite simple:  [USER_ID]=int(UserPrincipalName())
I found that the visual response time was now 13+ seconds.  As Power BI does the filtering in the model and not on the server.
Is there a good way for me to send that filter to the server so it only brings back the relevant data for the user?  Or how do I send the UserPrincipalName back to Azure Databricks if I want to setup RLS there?
I am in the information gathering phase now and haven't tried anything besides setting up RLS.  I did come across this post but haven't tried it yet.
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Creating-a-filter-based-on-USERPRINCIPALNAME/m-p/2441815
This video gets me part of the way it seems.  Although it requires me to have a chiclet slicer on the page at all times which I would prefer not to have.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyR0uAbLdTk

The UserPrincipalName can be sent from Power BI Service to Databricks for RLS using username() or userprincipalname() DAX functions, returning the UPN within Power BI. However, RLS filtering occurs on the client side, potentially slowing visual response times, as there's no direct method to filter data server-side.
